# Trimming image corners with border-radius set on parent div doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, safari, css

I have an image placed inside a div, the div has rounded corners which works as a mask to hide the image corners and display it as a circle. It works in all browser except for Safari! does anyone knows how to fix it?

I tried `-webkit-padding-box`, `-webkit-mask-box-image` but both didn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="cat"><img src="images/colorful-flowers-hd-wallpaper.jpg" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
.cat{
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    margin: 20px 96px 0px 96px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #111;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.cat img{
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    width: 138px;
    height: 138px;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/bDyKq/)

Comment: Related and helped me to find a solution (directly modifying the img): https://stackoverflow.com/q/15167545/1066234 using CSS `object-fit:cover;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make CSS3 rounded corners hide overflow in Chrome/Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera)

Comment: @Vega the question is specific to the Safari browser.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The best way around this is by specifying `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element.

Comment: Such a simple solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the fact that the parent element has `border-radius` applied to it but the image doesn't have any. The image tries to overflow and hence override the border-radius applied on the parent element.

**Simple Solution:**
In addition to setting the `border-radius` on parent element, you also need to add following CSS rule to the `img` tag:

```
img {
   border-radius: inherit;
}
```

**Caveat:**
If your image does not load correctly and you still want the border-radius to be applied, the above approach may not work and you may have to use the following CSS rule on the parent element:

```
div {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Note that `overflow: hidden` must be used with caution as it may interfere with other pseudo-elements you may have with respect to the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

What Safari version do you work with?

Several (unsatisfying) explanations for that problem:
[How to make CSS3 rounded corners hide overflow in Chrome/Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera)

You are taking out `<img />` of content flow with `position:absolute;`. 
By doing so, you should also change its display attribute to block. Then it makes sense to put border-radius on `img` too.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/LgYrz/ 
Note: On very old Webkits (Safari < 5.0)  [`-webkit-border-radius` is necessary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Another simple workaround is to add the `border-radius` property to the `img` tag as well, and give it the same value.

BTW you can use the HTML5 `figure` tag for containing images —I haven't tested it in more than a couple of browsers for awhile but last time I did it still needed the double `border-radius` workaround in an older Firefox.