# What is &::before, &::after in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a vertical timeline and I came across this page.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/oz2nu681

I copied the code and there are some things which I am having trouble with.

- &::after
- &::before
- .radio:checked;
  & + .relative;

I tried to change it into that stylesheet code but got stuck here.
Also the CSS code is different than what a traditional CSS file contains. What is this code and how do i use it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: `&` is SASS, not CSS.

Comment: It's SASS, not "pure" CSS. Click the wrench icon and you'll see.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question. Depending on how you interpret it, you seem to have about 8 questions here so it is likely to be closed for being too broad.

Comment: @Quentin actually if you look at the answer below you can see that OPs question can be answered with a single sentence... "It is SASS". OP will need to look up SASS and see if it will be useful for the project in mind, but overall it is answered.

Comment: @CayceK — Only one feature of that is SASS, the rest is CSS. The question doesn't say it is specifically about the ampersand and Adam's answer doesn't touch on any of the other features.

Comment: @Quentin that is fine and fairly true, but if he understands that the & (which to my assumption is really the primary focus here) is not a tool in CSS alone he can then search `:after` and `:before` and quickly learn the usefulness of those. Sometimes focusing on the most basic issue will answer a question. Reading into the whole thing is too much. Allow the user to develop their own learning overtime. Give them the base answer and build off of that more when comments arise.

Comment: Which is why people who ask questions that are too broad should be encouraged to narrow their question rather than receiving answers which ignore 80% of it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`&::after` is actually nothing in CSS, but it is a feature of SASS/SCSS and is probably written in a context like this:

```
li {
  /* some style 1 */

  &::after {
    /* some style 2 */
  }

}
```

Which compiles to:

```
li { /* some style 1 */ }
li::after { /* some style 2 */ }
```

Basically, the ampersand in SASS pulls in the parent selector when it compiles to CSS.

**EDIT**
You can't use the ampersand in a `.css` file, as it has no meaning, you can only use it in sass/scss files that are compiled to CSS using a SASS pre-processor.

Blog post (not mine) about ampersand in SASS:

http://www.joeloliveira.com/2011/06/28/the-ampersand-a-killer-sass-feature/

**EDIT 2**
Further answers:

Everything else is vanilla CSS, `::after`, `::before` are [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), `.relative` and `.radio` are [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors), `:checked` is a [pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) for input types radio and checkbox, and `+` is an [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

MDN should be (one) of your authorities for CSS documentation, so I chose to link to their pages rather than simply copy and paste the contents of their documents into this answer.

**EDIT 3**

I realized I didn't specifically state what `& + .relative` is.

I alluded to it initially when I said

> the ampersand in SASS pulls in the parent selector when it compiles to
>   CSS

In the OPs linked example there is this code:

```
.radio:checked
  & + .relative
    label 
       ... some styles here
```

When you consider that `& pulls in the parent selector` you'll see compiled CSS as this:

```
.radio:checked + .relative label { ... some styles here }
```

In "plain english", if you will:

An element with a class of radio that is checked with an immediate adjacent sibling element that has a class of relative and a child of that element with a tag name of label.

Comment: So what does `:after` mean? Or `:before`? Or `:checked`? or `+`? or `.relative`? or `.radio`? You've only touched on one of the things the question was asking about.

Comment: @Quentin ____ Adam: Do not waste your answer by going into a full description of all of that. If you feel the need point to W3Schools or some other useful resource. Your answer is very good as it answers what is needed here.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp Check it out here!

Comment: Came here to say I agree with @Quentin, I came here with the same question and still don't know what they do.