# IE and Edge fix for object-fit: cover;

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm using `object-fit: cover;` in my CSS for images on a specific page, because they need to stick on the same `height`. It works great in most browsers.

But when scaling my browser in IE or Edge, the image is resizing in `width` (not `height`) instead of zooming. The image gets out of shape.

What CSS rule can I use to fix this?

Here is the [page](http://www.homedecor.nl/onze-producten/raamdecoratie/)

Comment: It's just depressing that it doesn't work in Edge..

Comment: A nice solution over here that preserves the SEO benefits of using an img and some JS to handle the background ver for IE/edge browsers. https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3#.6smxr75ca

Comment: Faced the same problem recently. This lightweight polyfill had done the job like a charm :)
https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a  CSS solution to fix this.
Use the below css.

```
.row-fluid {
  display: table;
}

.row-fluid .span6 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.vc_single_image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.vc_single_image-wrapper .image-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

HTML from the OP:

```
<div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey">
  <div class="image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(http://i0.wp.com/www.homedecor.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Gordijnen-Home-Decor-2.jpg?fit=952%2C480;"></div>
</div>
```

try this, it should work. also remove float from `.row-fluid .span6`

Comment: I did it with a little twist. Also had to add 50% width and remove left:0 if I want to be on the right side. But it's very useful. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be broken.

Comment: @Dodekeract can you be more specific?

Comment: @Lucian [Run Code Snippet] does nothing for me on Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Literally just a white rectangle.

Comment: @Dodekeract did you even read all the question? and did you check the link provided by OP? the code i provided is just the solution, it won't work here in the snippet but works only when used in that case scenario.

Comment: Lucian Easy now, @Dodekeract is asking you to improve your answer for the benefit of the community.

Comment: @Lucian Could you please justify your statement : Here is the "only" CSS solution to fix this?

Comment: @MohammedFurqanRahamathM sorry I didn't get your point. do you need the explanation for the answer?

Comment: @Lucian Apologies for not being clear. I was wondering if you could explain why the approach you've taken is the 'only' way in CSS to answer the above question? Because I have my answer, in CSS, which uses a different approach but it still works. I wanted to understand your point.

Answer (score 40):

I had similar issue. I resolved it with **just CSS**.

Basically `Object-fit: cover` was not working in IE and it was taking 100% width and 100% height and aspect ratio was distorted. In other words image zooming effect wasn't there which I was seeing in chrome.

The approach I took was to position the image inside the container with  **absolute** and then **place it right at the centre** using the combination:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Once it is in the centre, I give to the image,

```
// For vertical blocks (i.e., where height is greater than width)
height: 100%;
width: auto;

// For Horizontal blocks (i.e., where width is greater than height)
height: auto;
width: 100%;
```

This makes the image get the effect of Object-fit:cover.

---

## Here is a demonstration of the above logic.

https://jsfiddle.net/furqan_694/s3xLe1gp/

This logic works in all browsers.

Comment: I like this approach, but its necessary to use javascript to detect the container's proportion when the container's size changes.

Comment: @RicardoFerreira True. This answer can be extended to work with a dynamic container.

Answer (score 20):

There is no rule to achieve that using CSS only, besides the `object-fit` (that you are currently using), which has partial support in EDGE<sup>**1**</sup> so if you want to use this in IE, you have to use a [object-fit polyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit) in case you want to use just the element `img`, otherwise you have to do some workarounds.

You can see the the `object-fit` support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

### UPDATE(2019)

You can use a simple JS snippet to detect if the  `object-fit` is supported and then replace the `img` for a `svg`

```js
//ES6 version
if ('objectFit' in document.documentElement.style === false) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        document.querySelectorAll('img[data-object-fit]').forEach(image => {
            (image.runtimeStyle || image.style).background = `url("${image.src}") no-repeat 50%/${image.currentStyle ? image.currentStyle['object-fit'] : image.getAttribute('data-object-fit')}`
            image.src = `data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='${image.width}' height='${image.height}'%3E%3C/svg%3E`
        })
    })
}

//ES5 version transpiled from code above with BabelJS
if ('objectFit' in document.documentElement.style === false) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.querySelectorAll('img[data-object-fit]').forEach(function(image) {
            (image.runtimeStyle || image.style).background = "url(\"".concat(image.src, "\") no-repeat 50%/").concat(image.currentStyle ? image.currentStyle['object-fit'] : image.getAttribute('data-object-fit'));
            image.src = "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='".concat(image.width, "' height='").concat(image.height, "'%3E%3C/svg%3E");
        });
    });
}
```

```css
img {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

[data-object-fit='cover'] {
  object-fit: cover
}

[data-object-fit='contain'] {
  object-fit: contain
}
```

```html
<img data-object-fit='cover' src='//picsum.photos/1200/600' />
<img data-object-fit='contain' src='//picsum.photos/1200/600' />
<img src='//picsum.photos/1200/600' />
```

### UPDATE(2018)

1 - EDGE has now [partial support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/objectfitandobjectpositionvideocanvasetc/) for `object-fit` since version 16, and by partial, it means only works in `img` element (future version 18 **still** has only partial support)

### [image: SS]

Comment: `background-size: cover` is the usual workaround for IE/Edge that solves most cases of this.

Comment: @TylerH yes, but then you have to change from `img` to `background img`

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but is background-img less good for SEO then an actual image?

Comment: img is better for SEO

Comment: Update for 2019 is the best answer right here. Minor note... you could make it a bit clearer that it needs to be transpiled. And I think ES5 might be too new, common might be better for compatibility. A link to an online transpiler that I used: https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: @Davey I have this note on top of the JS code `//for browsers which doesn't support object-fit (you can use babel to transpile to ES5)` I don't know if you saw that. Although I will update the answer to have the transpiled version as well

Comment: @dippas In addition, `background-image` is also not accessibility friendly.

Comment: @dippas On IE11 I get error for `forEach` method, it seems not supported. Could you provide a version of your solution compatible with IE11?

Comment: @dippas I tried with this polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach. Now I don't get error anymore, but it just doesn't add `style="..."` on the `<img>`, it just inject the code into `src="..."`, so I get no image as background. EDIT: maybe I'm wrong, it was IE11 console that doesn't show the style="" attribute but it shows in compiled tab!

Answer (score 12):

I just used the @misir-jafarov and is working now with :

- IE 8,9,10,11 and EDGE detection
- used in Bootrap 4
- take the height of its parent div
- cliped vertically at 20% of top and horizontally 50% (better for portraits)

here is my code :

```
if (document.documentMode || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    jQuery('.art-img img').each(function(){
        var t = jQuery(this),
            s = 'url(' + t.attr('src') + ')',
            p = t.parent(),
            d = jQuery('<div></div>');

        p.append(d);
        d.css({
            'height'                : t.parent().css('height'),
            'background-size'       : 'cover',
            'background-repeat'     : 'no-repeat',
            'background-position'   : '50% 20%',
            'background-image'      : s
        });
        t.hide();
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is also the correct answer so it's specific to IE.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this js code. Just change `.post-thumb img` with your `img`.

```
$('.post-thumb img').each(function(){           // Note: {.post-thumb img} is css selector of the image tag
    var t = $(this),
        s = 'url(' + t.attr('src') + ')',
        p = t.parent(),
        d = $('<div></div>');
    t.hide();
    p.append(d);
    d.css({
        'height'                : 260,          // Note: You can change it for your needs
        'background-size'       : 'cover',
        'background-repeat'     : 'no-repeat',
        'background-position'   : 'center',
        'background-image'      : s
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I achieved satisfying results with:

```
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
```

this way you always maintain the aspect ratio.

The complete css for an image that will replace "object-fit: cover;":

```
width: auto;
height: auto;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
position: absolute;
right: 50%;
transform: translate(50%, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

parent div:

```
height: 584px;
display: block;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #fff;
```

child img

```
object-position: center center;
min-height: 100%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
bottom: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
right: -9999px;
margin: auto;
width: auto;
min-width: 100%;
max-width: none;
-o-object-fit: cover; // you can keep them for modern browsers
object-fit: cover; // you can keep them for modern browsers
height: 100%;
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j6hLaxz8/

Comment: This is an ingenious solution, especially because you resolved this without resorting to `background-image`.