# Prevent stretching of an image while keeping dimensions

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to prevent the stretching of an image, to crop it somehow but keep the dimensions..?

```css
img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/d4/c3/dc/d4c3dc946ae1e087d24def574215e266--image-search-google-search.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the image fit a defined container with fixed dimensions, you can use `object-fit:cover`:

```css
div {
  height: 120px;
  width: 90px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/d4/c3/dc/d4c3dc946ae1e087d24def574215e266--image-search-google-search.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about using this property but it's not working in IE, is there something other way that you're aware of?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792720/ie-and-edge-fix-for-object-fit-cover

Answer (score 0):

To keep the exact same dimensions of this image you should only set one of the two dimensions. The other one will automatically be calculated:

```css
img {
  width: 90px;
  /*height: 120px;*/
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/d4/c3/dc/d4c3dc946ae1e087d24def574215e266--image-search-google-search.jpg" alt="">
```

Hope I helped out.

Comment: Dimensions should stay the same

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `width` and `height`, use `max-width` and `max-height`.

```
img {
  max-width:90px;
  max-height:120px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/n8h1mut6/)

Comment: Yeah, but it shortens the height