# How do I make a photo-gallery like Facebook?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, image-gallery

I am working on a 4x3 image gallery with pictures from a database.
All pictures have different sizes.
Using Bootstrap and CodeIgniter I make rows and columns for every image.
Now I want wide pictures to fit the height of the row, center horizontally and hide the horizontal overflow.
I also want that tall pictures fit the width of the column, center vertically and hide the vertical overflow. Just like Facebook.

margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; don't center the image.

My index page:

```
<h1><?=$title?></h1>

<?php $i = 1; foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    if ( $i % 3 == 1 ) { ?>
        <div class="row gallery-row">
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="gallery-image" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/<?php echo $photo['photo_name'];?>">
    </div>
    <?php if ( $i % 3 == 0 ) { ?>
        </div>
    <?php }
    $i++;
} ?>
```

My css:

```
.row.gallery-row{
    height: 25%;
}

.gallery-image{
    height : 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The closest I get is with the CSS above: The images fit the height of the row and overflow is hidden.
I still want the images to center and if the images are taller then wide they should prioritize fitting the width.
Here is what the page looks like [image]

The bottom left picture has a woman on it but it doesn't show because it isn't centered.

Solution: I changed my css to :

```
.gallery-image{
    height : 100%;
    width : 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

My page now looks like this: [image]
Adding some padding in between the rows will make it look just like facebook.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can help you. try to add to gallery-image class {display:block;margin:0 auto}

Comment: This does center smaller images but doesn't center the bottom left one.

Comment: i don't understand the problem for the image on the bottom left. Please provide us a fiddle so we can test your code

Comment: Here is the original image: https://mk0discoverbanfhesjg.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Banff-Gondola-View-in-the-Summer.jpg
As you can see if the image was centered in his container we would be able to see the woman.
What do you mean with a fiddle? How do I provide this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe adding [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) in your `.gallery-image` css is what you want.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.
I changed my css to .gallery-image{
    height : 100%;
    width : 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
My page now looks like this.
https://imgur.com/a/EZ3xTtW

Comment: it's ok to use it but remember this css property isn't supported by IE11

Comment: Nice :) There are [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37792830/6813732) [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47450998/6813732) that work for ie11.