# CSS Responsive Border-Radius Image

Tags: html, css, image, cornerradius

I want to make an image round (circle) from CSS, but, when I use `border-radius: 50%;` my image goes ellipsoidal.

I expect to output a responsive circle with that image.

How I can do that?

Thanks!

```css
#image {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  
  <figure id="img-div">
    <img id="image" src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/486693.jpg" alt="A bulb that represent electricity">
  </figure>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You should have height and width of the image same to have a circle

Comment: Ok, but then the image will be no more responsive, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167545/how-to-crop-a-rectangular-image-into-a-square-with-css

Check this to obtain the square image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by resizing your image just make your image same height and width like below..

this is only another way you can do it..

```css
#image {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  
  <figure id="img-div">
    <img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2ola.jpg" alt="A bulb that represent electricity">
  </figure>
  
</div>
```

Comment: The image must be a square, I undestand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **same height and width** in order for an element to be a circle.

```css
#image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  
  <figure id="img-div">
    <img id="image" src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/486693.jpg" alt="A bulb that represent electricity">
  </figure>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I got this, but now the  image will be no more responsive, right? I want to keep that circle image responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Your image needs to be square to obtain this result.

You can use this : [How to "crop" a rectangular image into a square with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167545/how-to-crop-a-rectangular-image-into-a-square-with-css) to keep it square and responsive.

After that, you radius will make it circle.

Comment: Don't hesitate to set it as an answer if this solved your issue. And no problem :)