# Does specifying WooCommerce product image ration crop the image from center/center?

Tags: woocommerce

Through the WordPress customizer, I want to crop some square images to be in the ratio of 400 x 250.

I'm concerned that doing so would crop the images from top left though.

Can the cropping occur from direct center of the image?

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38926886/667903) to generate the following CSS:

```
.search .et_pb_post a img {
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

This worked for me.